# Reasoning for alternate PHP syntax for conditional HTML

Tags: php, html, if-statement

So, why does this work:

```
<?php if (condition): ?>
    <!--html code here-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

But not simply this:

```
<?php
if (condition) { ?>
    <!--html code here-->
    <?
}
```

I figured it was just style preference, but I actually can't seem to get it to work the second way. Am I just doing something completely wrong? I can't see the purpose of outputting HTML right in the middle of an if statement if you wanted it to always print.

Comment: Both of them should work. You need to have short_open_tag enabled if you are going to use '<?' instead of '<?php'

Answer (score 4):

You need to allow short tag in your php.ini to make `<?` work

else you have to write `<?php } ?>`

Comment: +1 - remember folks, enabling short tags might blow up any XML files you are creating in PHP, i.e. MyXml.php, which starts <?xml ...

Comment: @sohnee: That's easy to get around. `$xml = '<' . '?xml'`, if for some reason you can't/won't avoid short tags.

Answer (score 0):

The second way should work like you described considering you have the closing php tags and < ?php

Comment: You don't need the closing tags (they are implicit). And you can use '<?' instead of '<?php' if you have short tags enabled.

Comment: Firstly, in the question the second example does not have a closing tag when the first one does. So you do need it if you are continuing with HTML. Secondly by default short tags are not set, such a question would indicate that defaults are set.

Answer (score 0):

It does, if you have the right re-opening tag...

```
<?php
if (condition) { ?>
    <!-- html code -->
<?php
}
```